# uuid not being saved in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, database

I'm trying to generate a UUID when a form is filled out and is posted to the server. MongoDB is picking up all the records except for userId. Ideally I want the UUID to be the parent, unique to each user (which I'll store in a cookie), and entry `search` submission will be the child of the UUID.

How come the UUID is not being stored along with the search data if it's being produced and available. I've changed the `userId` in the schema from `Number` to `String` with no avail.

Mongoose Schema

```
var SearchSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  userId: String,
  search: {
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String,
    email: String
  }
})
```

Save data to DB

```
  var firstName = req.body.firstName
  var lastName = req.body.lastName
  var email = req.body.email
  var userID = generateUUID()

  console.log(userID) // This works

  // Push to DB
  var data = new Search({
    userID: userID, // This doesn't appear to be stored
    search: {
      firstName: firstName,
      lastName: lastName,
      email: email
    }
  })

  Search.createSearch(data, function(err, search){
    if (err) throw err
    console.log('hello' + search)
  })
```

Console

```
{ search: 
   { email: '@rhysedwards.com',
     lastName: 'edwards',
     firstName: 'rhys' },
  _id: 5720d8211a44fac4dd6657c1 }
```

Answer (score 3):

Fields in MongoDB/Mongoose are case sensitive. Your schema calls the field `userId` but the object you store in the database has the field `userID`. Note the capitalization of the `D`.

Comment: Very good catch. I literally read the code over and over again and didn't notice.